# How to refresh just one DOM element using JS vanilla

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm using DOM to create an element for me that shows the amount of likes a specific comment has received. When someone likes the button that data gets pushed to the API. However, in order to see the number of likes increase I have to manually reload the page.

Is there a way to automatically refresh that specific DOM element so that when a user clicks the like button the amount of likes will automatically increase (so refresh) without having to manually reload the website?

```
    // shows the amount of likes
    const likeCounter = document.createElement("p");
    likeCounter.classList.add("comments__container-content-like-counter");
    functionsDiv.appendChild(likeCounter);
    likeCounter.innerText = commentData.likes;


    // likes a comment and adds it to the api
    commentLike.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const addLike = commentData.id;

        axios.put(`${baseURL}comments/${addLike}/like?api_key=${apiKEY}`).then(() => {
            console.log("Like has been added!");
        });
    });
```

Comment: So where does `commentData.likes;` come from? Does the call where you add the like return the new count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
 // shows the amount of likes

const likeCounter = document.createElement("p");
likeCounter.classList.add("comments__container-content-like-counter");
functionsDiv.appendChild(likeCounter);
likeCounter.innerText = commentData.likes;


// likes a comment and adds it to the api
commentLike.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const addLike = commentData.id;

    axios.put(`${baseURL}comments/${addLike}/like?api_key=${apiKEY}`).then(() => {
        console.log("Like has been added!");
        likeCounter.textContent = Number(likeCounter.textContent)+1
    });
});
```

Just add the line

```
likeCounter.textContent = Number(likeCounter.textContent)+1
```

to the promise chain.